# Number Theory Help for divisors

Tags: number-theory

how would i find n,a,b  such that n|ab but n does not divide a nor b.
Using arbitrary n,a,b values.
I think it has something to do with Bezout's identity but don't know how to apply it?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: In general, $n \mid ab \implies n \mid a \text{ or } n \mid b$ is true for prime $n$ only. So look for composite $n$.

Comment: just help on a example question, the answer is posted below already, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$6\mid 2\cdot 3$$
In genereal, if $a$ and $b$ are greater than one, you have
$$ab\mid ab$$
but $ab\nmid a$ and $ab\nmid b$.

In fact, the condition
$$n\mid ab\implies n\mid a\text{ or } n\mid b,$$
for all $a,b$, is equivalent of $n$ being a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I find $n,a,b$ such that $n$ divides $ab$ but $n$ does not divide neither $a$ nor $b$?

- Choose $a>1$
- Choose $b>1$
- Choose $n=ab$